# Shift parameter in a Matlab function

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

Suppose I have defined the symbolic function `x  -> f(x)` in Matlab. How can I define the function `x -> f(x+a)` starting from `f`? (here `a` is a real number)

I have tried `g = @(x) f(x+a)` but this definition only allows me to find values of `g`, but not its derivative. When I try to derivative `g` it says that it doesn't recognize `f` as a Matlab function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake is that you tried to define `g` as an anonymous function rather than a symbolic function. Instead, try symbolic substitution with [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html):

```
g = subs(f, x, x + a)
```